# Form isn't picking up the variables to post

Tags: php, html, forms

My test PHP submission code:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['create']) { echo $_POST['name']; }
?>
```

My HTML form code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="ConsultantSignUp" method="post" action="#">

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputForename">Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="input01"></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" rel="create" title="create" id="create" name="create">Create My Account</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

My error is that it doesn't even print out the name after submission. I've checked the PHP Error log and it says:

> PHP Notice: Undefined index: create in /Users/********/sites/signup.php on line 2

Line 2 being 'if($_POST['create']) { echo $_POST['name']; }'.

I'm aware of the isset() method to remove the Undefined Index notice, how ever, I just want to test my form!

Comment: Remove the `#` from action. Just leave `action=""`

Comment: Edited! I already had one.

Comment: No where in your form do you have a field named `create`, which is why it isn't being 'picked up'. - Edit, there it is in your edit.

Comment: use `var_dump($_POST);` in the beginning of your PHP code to get all posted data.

Comment: If I was you I will check if the post is not empty simply. If so I will do some kind of a logic. Take a look at the empty record and make sure to output the post data as s.webbandit suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my total code...This working perfectly for me in Chrome, Explorer and Firefox. Just check it

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['create'])) 
    { 
        echo $_POST['name']; 
    }
    else
    {
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="ConsultantSignUp" method="post" action="#">

<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="inputForename">Name</label>
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="name" name="name" rel="popover" data-content="Enter your first and last name." data-original-title="Full Name">
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="input01"></label>
    <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" rel="create" title="create" id="create" name="create">Create My Account</button>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: While the OP should do that, he is already aware of that (see the last paragraph of the question) and it won't solve the problem.

Comment: Ben just try out isset(), coz nw the post is working for me,,,,

Comment: Were you testing in Internet Explorer? The problem won't occur in older versions of that browser / in quirks mode due to bugs in IE.

Comment: How odd. Were you testing with the exact HTML from the question?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. A missing value causes it to be submitted with an empty string instead of not being a successful control.

Comment: yup with the same exact values, check my answer i have edited

Comment: Hi Pavan, this works perfectly. I had to remove the <input type="submit"> as it was creating another submit button next to mine! Thank you.

Comment: Yup you already had a button, so submit was unnecessary....good that it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<button ... name="create">` doesn't have a `value` so it will submit an empty string and `$_POST['create']` will evaluate as false.

Give it a value.

Answer (score 0):

the 'undefined index' NOTICE will go away when you use isset() function.
this often occurs when an unchecked checkbox is also posted.

the error is only there because no 'value' is passed on the submit button and the the submit button is POSTED empty.

replace submit button with,

```
<button value='submitbtn' type="submit" class="btn btn-success" rel="create" title="create" id="create" name="create">Create My Account</button>
```

PS ONLY (value='submitbtn') is added to your original button

Comment: i know, i was just telling that, the error is there because SUBMIT button is passed through NO VALUE. :)